# Joomla get('Items') and how it works

Tags: php, html, joomla, content-management-system

I am looking at line 34 of /administrator/components/com_contact/views/contacts/view.html.php where is says `$this->items       = $this->get('Items');` What I don't understand is how that is actually calling the `protected function getListQuery()` on line 123 of /administrator/components/com_contact/models/contacts.php

There are also some other things I don't understand how are working... like

```
$this->pagination   = $this->get('Pagination');
$this->state        = $this->get('State');
```

What are these calling? I looked at the documentation for "get()" but it doesn't say what these are actually calling because I don't see any methods called getPagination, getState or getItems... It appears the get('Items') is somehow magically calling getListQuery().

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*I'm presuming 1.7/2.5+ here...*

In Joomla!'s MVC the view `contacts` (`ContactViewContacts` which `extends JView`) automatically loads the model `contacts` (or in J! terminology `ContactModelContacts`) which as a class `extends JModelList`.

The `get()` looks in the view to get data from a registered model or a property of the view.

So;

```
$this->items = $this->get('Items');
```

is actually a call to the model `ContactModelContacts` which has a matching `getItems()` in it's `parent`.

The model file `com_contact/models/contacts.php` doesn't implement it's own `getItems()`, so the `getItems()` from the `JModelList` class is used (found in `/libraries/joomla/application/component/modellist.php`).

This in turn calls `getListQuery()` - no magic just inheritance.

The `$this->get('Pagination')` is doing the same thing, ie. accessing the implementation in the models parent.

The `$this->get('State')` is probably going all the way back to the `JModel` implementation.

Comment: Man do I feel like a moron... That makes too much sense.  I guess I have just never seen a Inherited method get called and then call a subclass method. I think I typed that correctly. Either way - THANK YOU!

Comment: Joomla component developer tutorial is responsible for this mess. I waste big time wandering about this mess(I imagined this would be the way but in the tutorial it was not there in 1.5 or 2.5). Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: I'd like to add that if anyone, including Ruwantha, is unhappy with any of the Joomla documentation,you can contribute to improving it. Joomla is an all volunteer project and it takes everyone's help to make it better.

Comment: One quick question. Do we have set() method also just like get()?